# If $A$ is an integer ring such that each $P \in A_L[X]$ has a finite number of zeros in $A$, is $A$ commutative?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, associative-algebras, division-rings

Let $A$ be a ring in which the product of any two nonzero elements is nonzero (we shall say that $A$ is an integral domain, even if $A$ is non commutative). It is well-known that if $A$ is commutative, then a non zero polynomial $P(X)\in A[X]$ has a finite number of zeros in $A$.

I deeply believe that the converse is also true. To state the conjecture, I need some natural definitions.

Define $A_L[X]$ the set of all left-polynomials, i.e expressions of the form $P(X)=a_nX^n+...+a_1X+a_0$ where $a_0, ..., a_n \in A$.

We say that $x\in A$ is a zero of $P$ if, and only if, $a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0=0$.

*CONJECTURE :* Let $A$ be a integral domain such that each $P(X)\in A_L[X]$ has a finite number of zeros in $A$. Then $A$ is commutative.

For instance, it is a direct generalization of Wedderburn's theorem : if $A$ is a finite field, then each left-polynomial over $A$ clearly have a finite number of zero in $A$.

I succeed to prove this result in the special case where $A$ is a field and the dimension of $A$ over its center $Z$ (seen as a $Z$-vector space) is finite. I used the article of [Gordon and Motzkin](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-116-00/S0002-9947-1965-0195853-2/S0002-9947-1965-0195853-2.pdf).

Is this conjecture known ? True ? False ?

Many thanks for your help ! Have a great week-end :)

Comment: What is an integer ring? In particular, are finite rings integer rings? What about the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, where $G$ is a free group?

Comment: The contrapositive of your conjecture is that if $A$ is noncommutative, then there is some polynomial with an infinite number of zeroes. This is clearly false if $A$ is finite, so you'll have to tell us whether "integer ring" excludes that possibility.

Comment: but English "integer" is not a translation of French "intègre" in any meaning!

Comment: Of course... I meant not necessarily commutative Integral domains.

Comment: Have you looked at the universal enveloping algebra of a nonabelian Lie algebra?

Comment: I am sorry Yuan, I haven't the mathematical background to understand your comment... Should I have a look at Lie algebras?

Comment: I would try anyway the case of a group algebra over a free group (as suggested by David Speyer) or over the Heisenberg group. I tend to believe that these are counterexamples to your conjecture.